# Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent

Tags: angular

when i tried running ng serve i have below error everytime
✘ [ERROR] NG2: Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/add-dog/add-dog.component.html:8:36:
  8 │     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.breed" />
    ╵                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component AddDogComponent.

```
src/app/add-dog/add-dog.component.ts:8:15:
  8 │   templateUrl: './add-dog.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/add-dog/add-dog.component.html:10:23:
  10 │     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.color" />
     ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component AddDogComponent.

```
src/app/add-dog/add-dog.component.ts:8:15:
  8 │   templateUrl: './add-dog.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

✘ [ERROR] NG2: Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/add-dog/add-dog.component.html:10:36:
  10 │     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.color" />
     ╵                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component AddDogComponent.

```
src/app/add-dog/add-dog.component.ts:8:15:
  8 │   templateUrl: './add-dog.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

✘ [ERROR] TS-992011: The component 'AddDogComponent' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/app.component.ts:8:12:
  8 │   imports: [AddDogComponent,ViewDogsComponent],
    ╵             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

✘ [ERROR] TS-992011: The component 'ViewDogsComponent' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/app.component.ts:8:28:
  8 │   imports: [AddDogComponent,ViewDogsComponent],
```

this is the code i have been using
src/add-dog.component.html

```
<div>
    <h2>Add a Dog</h2>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.name" />
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="formData.age" />
    <label>Breed:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.breed" />
    <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.color" />
    <button (click)="addDog()">Add Dog</button>
  </div>
```

src/app/app.component.html

```
<!-- src/app/app.component.html -->

<h1>Welcome to the Pet Adoption App!</h1>

<app-add-dog></app-add-dog>
<app-view-dogs></app-view-dogs>
```

src/app/app.module.ts

```
// src/app/app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AddDogComponent } from './add-dog/add-dog.component';
import { ViewDogsComponent } from './view-dogs/view-dogs.component';

// Import the DogService
import { DogService } from './services/dog.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AddDogComponent,
    ViewDogsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [DogService], // Add DogService to the providers array
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { AddDogComponent } from './add-dog/add-dog.component';
import { ViewDogsComponent } from './view-dogs/view-dogs.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AddDogComponent,ViewDogsComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

src/app/add-dog/add-dog.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DogService } from '../services/dog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-dog',
  templateUrl: './add-dog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-dog.component.css']
})
export class AddDogComponent {
  formData = {
    name: '',
    age: 0,
    breed: '',
    color: ''
  };

  constructor(private dogService: DogService) {}

  addDog() {
    this.dogService.addDog(this.formData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        alert(response.message);
        this.formData = { name: '', age: 0, breed: '', color: '' };
      });
  }
}
```

src/app/view-dogs/view-dogs.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DogService } from '../services/dog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-dogs',
  templateUrl: './view-dogs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-dogs.component.css']
})
export class ViewDogsComponent implements OnInit {
  dogs: any[] = [];

  constructor(private dogService: DogService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dogService.getDogs()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.dogs = response.dogs;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working example. I have gone with the default `standalone` behaviour, and all the components belonging to the dogs hierarchy are put into a separate module called `dogsModule`, where the necessary components are exported and then imported into the stand alone app component, which finally worked. Please find below the stackblitz example!

app component

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { DogModule } from './dog/dog.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [DogModule],
  
  template: `
    <h1>Welcome to the Pet Adoption App!</h1>
    <app-view-dogs></app-view-dogs>
    <app-add-dog></app-add-dog>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent);
```

dogs module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AddDogComponent } from '../add-dog/add-dog.component';
import { ViewDogsComponent } from '../view-dogs/view-dogs.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AddDogComponent, ViewDogsComponent],
  exports: [AddDogComponent, ViewDogsComponent],
})
export class DogModule {}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rihu6l)

Comment: thanks for looking in to the issue.  i have modified the code but got new error  ` The component 'ViewDogsComponent' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule. [plugin angular-compiler] ` . please let me know what am i missing.

Comment: @yashaswik can standalone true beauty removed? For app component, that will solve your issue!

Comment: i tried removing standalone true , i have this error now 'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.ts:7:11:
      7 │   imports: [AddDogComponent,ViewDogsComponent],

Comment: @yashaswik Please remove imports also

Comment: when i remove imports as well it boils down to initial error ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-add-dog' is not a known element: :(

Comment: @yashaswik Updated my answer with a working version, sorry for the confusions!

Comment: thanks for updated code, will make those changes.

Comment: @yashaswik If your issue is resolved, do give green tick!